# Get Multiple Check Box Values to View Data From MYSQL in TWIG

Tags: php, html, twig, symfony

This is my Controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $deployments = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Billing')
    ->findAll();
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array('deployments' => $deployments));
}

/**
 * @Route("/results", name="resultsPage")
*/
public function resultsAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('default/results.html.twig');
}                                                                                                                      

/**
 * @Route("/route/action/save", name="route-action-save")
 * @Method({"POST"})
*/
public function checkBoxAction(Request $request){

    return $arrayTenantID = $request->request->get('allvals');

}
```

The snippet of code below is in my index.html.twig file

```
<form>

    <div id="stuffTable">
        <table class="table table-hover" action="" method="post"> <thead> 
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/public/js/libs/jquery.min.js') }}">   </script>
            <tr> <th>Tenant ID</th> 
                <th>Tenant</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for stuff in deployments %}
            <tr> 
                <th scope="row">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="{{stuff.tenantID}}" id="tenantID">
                    <label for="tenantID">{{stuff.tenantID}}</label>
                    <td>{{stuff.tenantName}}</td> 
                </th>
            </tr> 
            {% endfor %} 
        </tbody> 
    </div>
</table> 
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
```

The table (image below) shows the TenantID and TenantName, but how do I use the checkbox so after clicking the "submit" button, another table will show data of the checked TenantIDs only?

To make my question a bit more clear,how do I save the TenantID values after they have been checked, so I can use it to Query the same table? I am using Doctrine to query.

[image: Screenshot]

```
<script>
function updateTextArea() {         
    var allVals = [];
    $('#stuffTable :checked').each(function() {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#textArea').val(allVals);

    sendData(allVals);
}
$(function() {
    $('#stuffTable input').click(updateTextArea);
    updateTextArea();
});

function sendData(allVals) {
$.ajax({
       url: "{{ path('route-action-save') }}",
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {"allVals": allVals},
       success: function(response){
            alert("hello");
       }

    });
}
```

This is my JavaScript and it seems to give me an error:
http://localhost:8000/route/action/save 500 (Internal Server Error)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the data will be in the GET\POST array after the form has been submitted

Comment: To save the data you need to this to be put within a `form` and defined controller action to handle , a route and a model to save data ...

Comment: @sakhunzai any advice on how to do it? I am working in the controller to get the data from AJAX

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you have the table with tenants Id:

```
<head>
   <script src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<table class="table table-hover"> <thead> 
    <tr> <th>Tenant ID</th> 
        <th>Tenant</th> 
    </tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody>           
    <tr> 
        <th scope="row">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tenantNum[]" value="1000">  1000</th> 
        <td>tenant_Name</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <th scope="row">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tenantNum[]" value="1001">  1001</th> 
        <td>tenant_Name</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <th scope="row">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tenantNum[]" value="1002">  1002</th> 
        <td>tenant_Name</td> 
    </tr> 

</tbody> 
</table>
<button type="button" id="tenant_id_button" >Ok</button>
```

Now, You could use Jquery and get multiple checkboxes values (checkboxes that you have been clicked) and after that, send it to php file (process_tenant.php)

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tenant_id_button').click(function () {

        //Get checked Id
        var array_tenant_id = new Array();
        $("input:checked").each(function () {
            array_tenant_id.push($(this).val());
        });
        //array_tenant_id = ["1000", "1002"] 

        $.ajax({
            url: "process_tenant.php",
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {"array_tenant_id": array_tenant_id},
            success: function (data) {
                //read response: data
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Now, you will get the checkboxes values server-side (file process_tenant.php)

```
<?php

$array_tenant_id = $_POST['array_tenant_id'];

var_dump($array_tenant_id);
```

The output will be an array with checkboxes previously checked:

```
 array(2) (
   [0] => (string) 1000
   [1] => (string) 1002
  )
```

** **If you use Symfony** **

Include Jquery library where you have the html table or include it in your base.html.twig

```
   <script src="{{ asset('bundles/public/js/libs/jquery.min.js') }}">   </script>
```

Now, send 'array_tenant_id' as parameter to your controller:

```
    $.ajax({
           url: "{{ path('route-action-save') }}",
           method: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {"array_tenant_id": array_tenant_id},
```

In the controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/route/action/save", name="route-action-save")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function saveSomething(Request $request) {   
        $array_tenant_id= $request->request->get('array_tenant_id');
```

Comment: I am working using Symfony framework, I was wondering if I can include this to my controller?

Comment: hey @rescobar where will I put the $.ajax? in the process_tenant.php?

Comment: @JaneDoe you have to put it in index.html.twig file or in the file where you have the html table, dont forget to include the library jquery.min.js in order to use Jquery in your html, have a look to post, I have added it. it.

Comment: Thanks, I made sure that the array part is working. I am working on the Ajax now. Do I have to add anything on the ajax part in order for the controller part to work?

Comment: No @JaneDoe, just include the library in the htm file as I mentioned above, for example:  <script src="{{ asset('bundles/public/js/libs/jquery.min.js') }}">   </script>

Comment: hey @rescobar I am having an issue, the error says "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "route-action-save" as such route does not exist.")." I have included the link on the twig file. Would you know how I will be able to fix this? Thank you

Comment: @JaneDoe,  Have you added  @Route("/route/action/save", name="route-action-save") in the controller? according to the example

Comment: I have updated my question. It is giving me an error, http://localhost:8000/route/action/save 500 (Internal Server Error), which is being caused by the Ajax. I am not sure what the error means. How do i check if the the controller is working properly?

Comment: Hey @JaneDoe,try this, if you want to see errors, you could use: http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/route/action/save , and your method  "checkBoxAction" has the annotation: @Method({"POST"}), it means that you can not access it because when you request (localhost:8000/route/action/save) the method is GET, you can change it to @Method({"GET"}) in order to testing it, and after that, change to POST again, remember that you request from the view using POST request.

Comment: I got it to work. thanks. On your example, $array_tenant_id= $request->request->get('array_tenant_id'); would you know how to check what is inside "$array_tenant_id" to make sure the IDs are inside?

Comment: @JaneDoe, if you want to determine if the variable is set and is not NULL, you could use "isset()" function, for example: if (isset($array_tenant_id)){ echo 'it is not null '; } else { echo 'it is null';}

Comment: but i wouldn't be able to just echo because the view is in twig, and im running on symfony3

Comment: would you know how I am able to render $array_tenant_id to a twig file, so I can see if the array is not empty? Thanks

Comment: Sure @JaneDoe, if you want yo chek if the array or another variable is empty, take a look to this link: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tests/empty.html , render it: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html